# Running PACT test is throwing a Ruby Load Error

Tags: ruby, pact

I am trying to run a pact test for a typescript/angular service, from Visual Studio Code .I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR (15568 ): pact-node@10.11.11: Pact Binary Error: C:/projects/App/sample.webapp/node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-node/standalone/win32-1.88.40/pact/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
`require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (ERROR (15568): pact-node@10.11.11: Pact Binary Error: LoadError)
from C:/projects/App/sample.webapp/node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-node/standalone/win32-1.88.40/pact/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

Comment: Any idea what this Load error is about? Is it a version mis match? How can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the infamous [windows long path issue](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js-core/issues/100). See that issue for further details, but the simplest option is to move your project directory closer to the root of `c:`.

For context, Ruby is bundled into Pact JS as a core engine for matching, broker interaction, and verification logic. Our v3 (which does not suffer this issue) is going to have a rust core, you can try out the beta here: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/#pact-js-v3

Comment: Thank you .  I scrubbed the path, moved it closer to the C: but nothing seems to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was resolved in Ruby v3.0.2 (see this PR https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/4505). Though contributors are not going to repack Pact library with the latest Ruby version and still suggest to workaround the problem by locating your project directory close to the root c:\ or start using pact-js v3.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30171370)